# Personalizar a mensagem de erro do Nginx

Tags: nginx

Olá, o servidor Nginx tem uma mensagem que aparece de vez em quando nos sites como **502 Bad Gateway**. Tem como personalizar essa mensagem via SSH nos arquivos do Nginx?

> Instalei a partir desse tutorial: http://www.nginxcp.com/installation-instruction

O que queria era por uma mensagem em português para usuários "leigos". Tem alguma forma de personalizar?

Answer (score 2):

Todos os erros podem ser modificados.

Primeiramente crie um arquivo e dê um nome, por exemplo: `500.html`.

Irei colocar isto no diretorio `/usr/share/nginx/error/`, isso irá impedir que acessar o `meusite.com/500.html` exiba o erro, por padrão o diretorio do site é o `usr/share/nginx/html/`. ;)

Altere as configurações para:

```
error_page 502 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/error;
}
```

Normalmente o diretorio do arquivo que deve alterar é `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`, no CentOS.

Para melhor demonstração deve ficar algo assim:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  meusite.com.br;

        location / {
               root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
               index index.php  index.html index.htm;
        }


        error_page 502 /500.html;
        location = /500.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/error;
        }

    //...

}
```

Comment: Irei fazer um teste e postarei o resultado! Muito obrigado por sua resposta!